# Physics SE is for who?

Tags: discussion

Are non-physicists allowed to ask questions on physics SE?

I get the impression that only people with a good (vast?) knowledge of physics are allowed to ask questions here.

Should we turn people away when they say theyre 16 years old  or e.g. if someone expresses a lack of understanding of unitarity or if they dont know whatthe weinberg mixing angle is?

Or is it that anyone is open to ask questions here and shouldnt be driven away or belittled?

Sorry if this is known...im still learning the culture and rules here

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes.  Itd be good to know how much physics background a user should have before asking a question

Comment: There is no requirement for the level of physics knowledge one has.

Comment: @0celo7 that would be ideal but that's not what ive gathered from observation (which prompted my question).  E.g. one should totally know that absolute zero is not experimentally or theoretically  obtainable

Comment: We have many high rep undergraduates, along with a fair number of high rep high schoolers, and even a few active middle schoolers. There's no requirement, as long as one is humble and writes good questions.

Comment: From my experience, though, tone matters a lot. A generic naive question like "Why do physicists do X?" usually gets upvotes, even if it's middle school level. But if it's phrased like "*wHY* have *physics* **NOT REALIEZD** that X is **USELESS**" it's sure to get downvoted to hell.

Comment: @user122066 If one asks a question about stuff near absolute zero, yeah. It's called doing research.

Comment: Basically, I think your original question could have been well received if it were phrased better. You want to remove most explanation points and question marks, almost all bold and italics, and every instance of all caps. Then spell check and split into paragraphs.

Comment: Then change the tone. Sometimes, you've written in a 'conspiratorial' way, as if 'physicists' or 'high rep users' are some cabal out to get you. You got downvoted, not because there actually is a cabal, but because nobody likes to be call that. We're all humans here.

Comment: @knzhou no clue what youre talking about. There are no bold letters, paragraphs, or exclamation marks in my question.....this is a question about the requirements to ask questions on physics SE.....

Comment: @0celo7 so not having quantum mechanics under one's belt at 16yrs old and asking about absolute zero implies the person shouldnt ask? I got a doctorate in physics and i didnt know the quantum mechanics of absolute zero at age 16! I couldnt imagine very many 16year olds having that knowledge.  So 16 year olds have a high probability of not being allowed to ask question

Comment: But at least a few have come to physics SE looking for that knowledge only to be belittled for not knowing it apriori or for making a small mistake in thier question.....seems ridiculous to me to require absolute zero knowledge as the baseline to ask questions about physics.

Comment: But if that's the requirement then thats the requirement. Im just looking for some kind of consensus or definition of how much physics background is required.  Based on your argument of the example users should have undergrad quantum and thermodynamics

Comment: @knzhou i have no clue what youre talking about here either. This is a question about what requirements a user should have before asking questions on physicsSE. No cabal, no conspiracies, just a question about requirements.  Weve so far determined that 16 years old is likely too young as they have not yet learned about absolute zero

Comment: @user122066, I'm a middle schooler. I would certainly say I'm not very well versed in physics. However, I'd call myself decently active. There truly isn't a limit on who can participate. I don't know a ton about absolute zero. However, I can google it and look at the Wikipedia page and figure something out about it. If I have a question about what that says, then I'll ask it. The point isn't that no one can ask a question about absolute zero. The point is you have to show you looked into it a little yourself. If you ask, "What is absolute zero?" you'll get downvoted into oblivion. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) However, if you ask, "Hey, I read x on the wikipedia page about absolute zero, and with y in mind, x doesn't make sense. Could you help me out here?" You'll get an answer. It's not about level of topic, but about effort in it. That's just my two cents.

Answer (score 7):

From the [help center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic),

> Physics Stack Exchange is for active researchers, academics and students of physics and astronomy.

People who are not in that target audience may have a bit of a harder time asking questions, because our sense of what constitutes a good question is calibrated to the kinds of questions that students and (sometimes) researchers ask.

However, there are no level requirements, not in the sense of "you must know [topic] and [topic] etc. to ask a question here". We only expect that people ask questions which are appropriate to whatever level they are at. In short, don't ask a question for which you're not prepared to understand the answers. For example, if someone who's never studied quantum mechanics asks about the uncertainty principle, it's likely not going to be well received. Similarly if someone who's never studied relativity asks about the interior of a black hole. Or if a complete layperson, who's never studied even basic kinematics, asks about, say, calculating orbits. (These are all rough guidelines; any specific case could be an exception, depending on how the question is asked.)

We also expect that people do a bit of research before asking their questions, enough to get acquainted with the topic and make *some* progress toward solving their problem. For example, as was brought up in the comments, someone asking a question about absolute zero would be expected to do enough research to know that it's impossible to make a real object have that temperature.